# Sikuli doesn't see the game I'm trying to automate

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I'm running Sikuli API from Java on a game we are running in the company on full screen. The problem is that Sikuli sees the layer beneath the game (the desktop) but not the game itself. It's like the game is transparent to Sikuli. I took a screenshot through RobotFW and also, the image I'm getting is the layer beneath. So this looks like a general issue and not specific to Sikuli.

What can I do?

The games are developed in Unity

Comment: Is that on mac?

Comment: no, it's on Windows 7

Comment: What if you use a `App.focus(<appName>)` before executing your code?

Comment: solved by using App.focus. thank you very much Tenzin!!

Comment: I suggest @Tenzin to post the answer and for Dotan Raz to accept it. This way it is more likely to help other users who experiences the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use a `App.focus(<appName>)` before executing your code?

By using `App.focus()` you pull that application to the foreground.